# Flutter web - Chrome Extension - Migrate manifest version 2 to 3

Tags: flutter, google-chrome-extension

i try to migrate manifest in v2 to v3

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "name": "chrome_extension",
  "description": "A new Flutter project.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icons/icon-192.png",
      "32": "icons/icon-192.png",
      "48": "icons/icon-192.png",
      "128": "icons/icon-192.png"
    }
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src https://unpkg.com/canvaskit-wasm@0.30.0/bin/canvaskit.js;"
},
```

my new manifest doesn't work

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "name": "chrome_extension",
    "description": "A new Flutter project.",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "icons/icon-192.png",
            "32": "icons/icon-192.png",
            "48": "icons/icon-192.png",
            "128": "icons/icon-192.png"
        }
    },
    "content_security_policy": {
        "extension_pages": "https://unpkg.com/canvaskit-wasm@0.30.0/bin/canvaskit.js;",
        "sandbox": "script-src 'self' ; object-src 'self'"
    }
}
```

Any idea ?

i generate the chrome extension : flutter build web --web-renderer html

Comment: ManifestV3 doesn't allow external scripts.

Comment: So, it's not possible to generate a chrome extension with canvaskit ?

Comment: Download it and ship the files within the extension like your own scripts.